# LEFT JOIN работает не так как я ожидал

Tags: sql-server

Необходима помощь со скриптом. Есть таблица `Request` c полем `Request.uf_field`, в котором может быть указан как `udv.id` так и `NULL`. Запрос считает все заявки с заполненным или пустым `Request.uf_field`, но мне так же необходимо чтобы в столбце `udv_name` указывались и те значения `udv.name`, которые не были перечислены в `Request.uf_field`. По такому условию `udv.userdirectory_id = 6007`. Разные варианты пробовал, но все пальцем в небо. Спасибо за помощь.

[image: Таблица Request] [image: Таблица udv] [image: Ожидаемый результат]

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(udv.name, '(empty)') AS udv_name,
  COUNT (Request.id) AS request_count
FROM
  Request
  LEFT JOIN udv
    ON Request.uf_field = udv.id
GROUP BY
  udv.name
ORDER BY
  udv.name
```

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно использует `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Request TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, uf_field INT);
INSERT INTO @Request (uf_field) VALUES
(504),(504),
(NULL), (502),
(507), (504),
(502), (NULL),
(504), (505);

DECLARE @Udv TABLE (ID INT, [Name] VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Udv (ID, [Name]) VALUES
(501, 'foo'),
(502, 'bar'),
(503, 'tro'),
(504, 'lolo'),
(505, 'para'),
(506, 'pa'),
(507, 'pam'),
(508, 'cpp');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT r.uf_field
        , u.[Name]
    FROM @Udv AS u
        FULL OUTER JOIN @Request AS r ON r.uf_field = u.ID
)
SELECT COALESCE([Name], '(empty)') AS [Name]
    , COUNT(IIF(rs.name IS NULL, 1, uf_field)) AS RequestCount
FROM rs
GROUP BY [Name];
```

**Результат**

```
+---------+--------------+
|  Name   | RequestCount |
+---------+--------------+
| (empty) |            2 |
| bar     |            2 |
| cpp     |            0 |
| foo     |            0 |
| lolo    |            4 |
| pa      |            0 |
| pam     |            1 |
| para    |            1 |
| tro     |            0 |
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Спасибо, поэкспериментировал с Вашим решением, но для меня пока оно немного сложное, использовал другое.

Comment: Если предложенное решение работает для вас, даже если вы его не совсем понимаете, не забудьте пометить его как Ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, но вроде вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
SELECT
       udv.name  AS udv_name,
       COUNT(request.id) AS request_count
FROM request
LEFT JOIN udv ON request.uf_field = udv.id
GROUP BY udv.name
UNION
SELECT
       udv.name  AS udv_name,
       COUNT(request.id) AS request_count
FROM request
RIGHT JOIN udv ON request.uf_field = udv.id
GROUP BY udv.name
ORDER BY udv_name
```

Если добавить во вторую таблицу поле Null, можно будет обойтись без объединения и просто заменить на Right Join в вашем коде

Comment: Спасибо, использовал юнион и вложенный селект.